# Python convert matrix with relations to list

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matrix, data-conversion

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
    a   b   c   d
a   0   1   0   0
b   0   0   1   1
c   1   0   0   1
d   1   0   0   0
```

Where the 1 represents a one way relationship between the rows and columns.
ex:

```
a interacts with b
b interacts with c and d
c interacts with a and d
...
```

What I need is a list with three columns that ignores the 0s and lists the interactions.
ex:

```
a  1  b
b  1  c
b  1  d
c  1  a
...
```

Currently I am using numpy and reading the initial matrix from a csv file.

```
data = np.array(list(csv.reader(open("input.csv"))))
```

Comment: How do we get headers and indexes for a matrix? Show us a minimal sample that could be copied and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I create my toy data matrix a:

```
a = numpy.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
coords = ('a', 'b')
for i in range(len(coords)):
    for j in range(len(coords)):
        if a[i,j]:
            print coords[i], 1, coords[j]
```

it outputs:

```
a 1 b
b 1 a
```

Comment: Thank you, i was able to take your suggestion and implement it fitting it to my data.